# String array of fixed size memory allocation in java

Tags: java, string

```
String str[] = new String[3];
```

Can someone explain to me the memory map for the above line. How many objects and ref it will have?

Answer (score 7):

That line allocates one object, which is an array of three String references. These references are initialized to `null` by default.

It also defines `str` as a local variable holding a reference to an array of Strings. It initializes the variable with a reference to that object it just created.

So you have this diagram:

```
str (local variable)
    +--------+             array object    
    |   -----+---------> +-------------+
    +--------+           |    null     | (can hold a reference to a String)
                         +-------------+
                         |    null     | (can hold a reference to a String)
                         +-------------+
                         |    null     | (can hold a reference to a String)
                         +-------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

new String[3] will create one object, array of 3 String references, initialized with nulls. Object size (for 32-bit JVM) = header(8) + length(4) + 3 references (4 bytes each)

Answer (score 0):

It will Have one Array instance with the reference of 3 String objets.

Answer (score 0):

Also, noticing that you are probably new to this(might just be a typo, sorry if I am wrong), a correction to your post.
The correct syntax in your code snippet should be

```
String[] str = new String[3];
```